# Is there a method like append for dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

How do i add key,value to a dictionary in python?
I defined an empty dictionary and now I want to pass a bunch of keys from a list and set their value as 1. From what I did it creates me every iteration a new dictionary, but I want to append the key,value so eventually I will recieve only one dictionary. 
this is my code:

```
def count_d(words):
    count_dict={} 
    words_set= set(words)
    for i in words_set:
        count_dict[i]= 1
        print (count_dict)
```

Comment: "But I want to append the key,value so eventually I will recieve only one dictionary" -- Can you explain?  The code you have only creates a single dictionary.  Perhaps you want to `return count_dict` after the for loop has been completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [dict.fromkeys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) along with [dict.update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

**From the docs**

> Create a new dictionary with keys from seq and values set to value.

**Example Usage**

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(dict.fromkeys(range(10), 1))
>>> d
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}
```

Note, you need an `dict.update` along with `dict.fromkeys`, so as to update the dictionary in-place

Instead, if you want to create a dictionary and assign use the notation

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(range(10), 1)
>>> d
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}
```

Unfortunately, for in-place update, you need to create a throw-away dictionary before passing to the  `dict.update` method. A non-intuitive method is to leverage [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import izip, repeat
d.update(izip(xrange(10), repeat(1)))
```

The same idea can be extended to [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which is often used, as an alternate for `OrderedSet` as standard library does not provide one.

Answer (score 2):

the `fromkeys` method does what you want:

```
count_dict = dict.fromkeys(words_set, 1)
```

This gives `count_dict` it's keys from `words_set`, each with value of 1.

More info on `fromkeys` [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_fromkeys.htm)

Comment: No it doesn't. `fromkeys` does not mutate `count_dict`, it returns a new dict. Plus, it's a class method, not an instance method, so there is no reason to create a new dict just to call it on.

Comment: Apologies and thanks, I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

> How do i add key,value to a dictionary in python?

Exactly as you are:

```
count_dict[i] = 1
```

> From what I did it creates me every iteration a new dictionary

No it doesn't. It keeps appending to the same iteration. The problem is that you print the dictionary-so-far on every iteration.

So, you were very close to what you wanted. I believe that all you want to do is unindent the `print` statement, so it only happens once at the end, instead of each time through the loop:

```
def count_d(words):
    count_dict={} 
    words_set= set(words)
    for i in words_set:
        count_dict[i]= 1
    print (count_dict)
```

Of course it will probably be a lot more useful to `return count_dict`, not print it. And Abhijit's answer shows a much simpler way to do this. (Another simple way to do it: `count_dict = dict(collections.Counter(words_set))`. But I think `dict.from_keys` is more meaningful in this case, despite your variable names.)

But I think this is the part you were actually struggling with.